# extract number after specific string

Tags: regex, r, stringr

I need to find the number after the string "Count of". There could be a space or a symbol between the "Count of" string and the number. I have something that works on www.regex101.com but does not work with stringr `str_extract` function.

```
library(stringr)

shopping_list <- c("apples x4", "bag of flour", "bag of sugar", "milk x2", "monkey coconut 3oz count of 5", "monkey coconut count of 50", "chicken Count Of-10")
str_extract(shopping_list, "count of ([\\d]+)")
[1] NA NA NA NA "count of 5" "count of 50" NA
```

What I want to get:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA "5" "50" "10"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
str_extract(shopping_list, "(?i)(?<=count of\\D)\\d+")
# [1] NA   NA   NA   NA   "5"  "50" "10"
```

where `(?i)` makes the pattern case insensitive, `\\D` means not a number, and `?<=` is a positive lookbehind.

Comment: I was thinking of a lookbehind but if the data has a slight variation it will fail. Try `"coconut count of - 5"`

Comment: @PierreLafortune, true, but in this case I understand that there can be only one symbol between "f" and a number.

Comment: This is the query that is providing the value that I need using just the regex. Thank you!

Comment: @Julius is it possible to make the `\\D` any number of non-numeric, non-character variable?

Comment: @MatthewCrews, unfortunately, as far as I know, positive lookbehind allows only for a text of predefined length, so no (if we want to maintain the same spirit as in this answer). That is what Pierre Lafortune had in mind is his comment.

Comment: @Julius, thank you for the information. The reason I did not accept Pierre's answer was because it was returning text from every element of the vector and then depended on the `as.numeric` function to eliminate the elements which did not have a value of interest. This answer actually extracts the element of interest using just RegEx.

Answer (score 3):

Look ahead and look behinds are what you are looking for with this grep...

```
shopping_list <- c("apples x4", "bag of flour", "bag of sugar", "milk x2", "monkey coconut 3oz count of 5", "monkey coconut count of 50", "chicken Count Of-10")
str_extract(shopping_list, "(?<=count of )[0-9]*")
[1] NA   NA   NA   NA   "5"  "50" NA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
as.numeric(sub("(?i).*count of.*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", shopping_list))
[1] NA NA NA NA  5 50 10
```

The regex pattern is:

- `(?i)`: Ignore case
- `.*count of.*?`: Any length of characters up to "count of"
- `(\\d+)`: Capture one or more digits
- `"\\1"`: Return the capture group

As of now the other answers will fail with something like `""coconut count of - 5"` since they are constrained by one space after "count of".