# Extract number after a certain word

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to build a regex expression to extract a 6 digit number (positive or negative) after a certain string, namely 'LogL='.

It comes from text output from certain software.

```
   7 LogL=-3695.47     S2=  9.0808       1891 df    2.263     0.2565    
   9 LogL= 2456.30     S2=  1.2789       1785 df    1.244     0.1354
```

I tried the following in R:

```
txt <- "   9 LogL= 2456.30     S2=  1.2789       1785 df    1.244     0.1354   "
as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(sub(".*LogL=*", "", txt), " "))[1])
```

Doesn't work for positive numbers. And I imagine its very crude/ugly way of going about it.
I tried meddling on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/wZ6gE1/2)

Stackoverflow related questions tried: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947123/r-stringr-extract-number-after-specific-string) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215789/extract-a-substring-in-r-according-to-a-pattern) [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451251/extract-numeric-part-of-strings-of-mixed-numbers-and-characters-in-r)

I am kind of lost and can't seem to understand regex expressions. I am sure this is a piece of cake. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd use a [look-behind regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
txt <- "   7 LogL=-3695.47     S2=  9.0808       1891 df    2.263     0.2565    
           9 LogL= 2456.30     S2=  1.2789       1785 df    1.244     0.1354   "
pattern <- "(?<=LogL\\=)\\s*\\-*[0-9.]+"
m <- gregexpr(pattern, txt, perl = TRUE)
as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(txt, m)))
#1] -3695.47  2456.30
```

Comment: Appreciate the link and the answer! Need to start learning regex expressions. They are very useful it seems.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
LogL=\s*(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)
```

It matches your text (LogL), an equal sign followed by any number of spaces. Then it captures:

- an optional `-`
- digits, at least one
- and optionally, a `.` followed by at least one digit.

[Check it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/wZ6gE1/3).

Comment: Thanks! Also appreciate the explanation. Helps me understand regex 'clutter'.

Answer (score 3):

If you can be interested in a non regex alternative:

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "   9 LogL= 2456.30     S2=  1.2789       1785 df    1.244     0.1354   "
word(txt, 2, sep = "=") %>% word(2, sep = " ")
```

It works with positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract`

```
 library(stringr)
 as.numeric(str_extract_all(txt, "(?<=LogL=\\s{0,1})[-0-9.]+")[[1]])
 #[1] -3695.47  2456.30
```

---

Or we can use a combination of `strsplit` and `gsub`

```
as.numeric(gsub(".*LogL=\\s*|\\s+.*", "", trimws(strsplit(txt, "\n")[[1]])))
#[1] -3695.47  2456.30
```

Comment: No idea. Thanks a lot for your answer :)