# How to get a sum of numbers in a character string?

Tags: r

Character String is like this.

```
test <- c("John got a score of 4.5 in mathematics and scored 4.3 in English and ranked 4th.", "Matthew got a score of 7.6")
```

Output desired is c(8.8, 7.6).

Basically sum of numbers after **"score"** pattern.

I tried:

```
s <- as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "^\\D*score\\D*(\\d+\\.*\\d*)\\D*score*\\D*(\\d*\\.*\\d*)\\D*$", replacement = ("\\1"), test$Purpose)) + 
        as.numeric(gsub(pattern = "^\\D*score\\D*(\\d+\\.*\\d*)\\D*score*\\D*(\\d*\\.*\\d*)\\D*$", replacement = ("\\2"), test$Purpose))
```

However this is returning NAs.

Comment: Almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35947123/r-stringr-extract-number-after-specific-string . I got it with `str_extract_all(test, "(?i)(?<=score of\\D)\\d+.\\d+|(?i)(?<=scored\\D)\\d+.\\d+")`

Comment: `sum(as.numeric(strsplit(test, ' ')[[1]]), na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

We can extract the numbers with regex and then do the `sum`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(test, "(?<=score of )[0-9.]+|(?<=scored )[0-9.]+"),
                      function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))
#[1] 8.8 7.6
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
str_extract_all(test, "\\b[0-9.]+\\b") %>%
      map_dbl(~ as.numeric(.x) %>%
                           sum)
#[1] 8.8 7.6
```

Or if we need to get only the numbers after `score`

```
str_extract_all(test, "(?<=score of )[0-9.]+|(?<=scored )[0-9.]+") %>%
     map_dbl(~ as.numeric(.x) %>%
                           sum)
```